# ColSum of matrix from file python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to calculate the column sum of a list of lists.  I used to for loops and i still cant get it to calculate. Should work with any size list. I can't use numpy or anything like that.

numbers are

```
1 5 3
8 6 2
6 2 7
```

here is code

```
def main():
    filNam = "matrix8.txt"
    matrix = (readMatrix(filNam))
    rowNum = 0
    colNum = 0
    print(matrix)
    (colSum(matrix, colNum))

def readMatrix(filNam):
    matrixList = []
    numFile = open(filNam, "r")
    lines = numFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        row = []
        for i in line:
            row.append(int(i))
        matrixList.append(row)
    return matrixList

def eachNumPresent(matrix):
    if len(matrix) % 2 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def rowSum(matrix, rowNum):
    for i in matrix[rowNum]:
        i = sum(matrix[rowNum])
        rowNum += 1
        print(i)

def colSum(matrix, colNum):
    for j in matrix[colNum]:
        total = 0
        for i in matrix:
            total += matrix[i][j]
        print(total)

main()
```

Comment: Can you use a list comprehension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the numbers from the file and construct the matrix, with *List Comprehension*

   ```
   >>> with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
   ...     matrix = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in in_file]
   ...     
   ... 
   >>> matrix
   [[1, 5, 3], [8, 6, 2], [6, 2, 7]]
   ```
2. Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function to transpose the `matrix`, so that the rows become columns and vice-versa.

   ```
   >>> matrix  = zip(*matrix)
   >>> matrix
   [(1, 8, 6), (5, 6, 2), (3, 2, 7)]
   ```
3. In fact, *instead of step 2*, you can find the sum of columns in the same line, like this

   ```
   >>> sums = [sum(row) for row in zip(*matrix)]
   >>> sums
   [15, 13, 12]
   ```

**Edit:** Since `zip` is not allowed, you can roll your own `zip` function like this

```
>>> def transpose(matrix):
...     return [[matrix[j][i] for j, column in enumerate(row)] for i, row in enumerate(matrix)]
... 
>>> 
>>> with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
...     matrix = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in in_file]
...     
... 
>>> [sum(row) for row in transpose(matrix)]
[15, 13, 12]
>>>
```

Since `enumerate` is also not allowed, you can find the sum of columns using plain `for` loops, like this

```
>>> def get_column_sums(matrix):
...     result = [0] * len(matrix[0])
...     for i in range(len(matrix)):
...         for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
...             result[j] += matrix[i][j]
...     return result
... 
>>> 
>>> get_column_sums(matrix)
[15, 13, 12]
```

Comment: i cant use the zip function havent talked about in class

Comment: @solofisher Can you please list down the things which are allowed or not allowed in the question itself? I spent 15 minutes on preparing this answer.

Comment: sorry about that.  Basically i can u for loops, while loops. I cant use enumerate or numpy or any other function or library. I can use basically what i have in my question.

Comment: dude, if you spent as much time on your homework as you just did searching SO and critiquing responses that were given to you, you'd have it done all by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you tried to really complicate things.

Create a *name* for each column that you can use to accumulate the values.

```
col0 = 0
col1 = 0
col2 = 0
```

For each line in the file, extract each character.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        c0, c1, c2 = line.strip().split()
```

Add each character to the appropriate *name*.

```
        col0 += int(c0)
        col1 += int(c1)
        col2 += int(c2)
```

I accented *names* and purposely did not use *variables* because of this:
http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables